# Background img doesn`t display in all Android broswers

Tags: android, css, image, background, cover

Using all browsers on Computer (chrome, safari, opera, edge) the background image in footer is displayed fine. But using browsers in ANDROID the background image does NOT displayed. In the other hand, using an iPhone (safari, chrome) my image in footer is displayed!!! The only bug/problem there is on Android`s browsers.

```
<footer class="footer" style="background-image: url('img/creative/backgrounds/lll.jpg')">

//Css Code
footer.footer {
  color: white;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  padding: 255px 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: there is no way to fix that. i had same problem. i tried everything...

Comment: axxxx! thanks man anyway...;/

Comment: found the problem. very big the dimensions of the image.. i have changed it with another smaller image. @felixsturm